# Oracle Apex - Automatically download reports

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I have an Oracle application with several reports.

How can I make it automatically downloaded, periodically(daily or weekly), to a shared folder in sharepoint?

Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: not through apex thats for sure

Comment: May be Interactive Report email subscription would be acceptable?